# How to get Step Name and Step Execution ID in ItemReadListener?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My Spring Batch job uses a `FlatFileItemReader` to read .csv files. To implement error handling, I created a custom `ItemReadListener` and provided an overridden `onReadError` implementation.

Here, I'd like access to the `StepName` and `StepExecutionId` from which the error was thrown (i.e. at the reader level). Can I access the `StepExecution` in the my custom listener? When I try to inject it into any method or constructor, I get a "No beans of type StepExecution found" error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following in your ItemReadListener.

```
@Value("#{stepExecution}")
private StepExecution stepExecution;
```

This should work if the scope is step. Also your ItemReadListener should be a spring bean.