# How to stop spring batch job using kafkaitemreader class to read from kafka topic, after certain time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

My spring batch job reads from kafka topic and writes to a flat file. It is running continuously for days and i want to stop the job successfully after certain time (for eg. i want to stop the job successfully after 5 hours or it can stop anytime before that depends on data present on topic).

Comment: The KafkaItemReader returns `null` if no records are present after the [pollTimeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html#setPollTimeout-java.time.Duration-) (which defaults to 30 seconds), and this should end the step. Where is your job waiting exactly?

Comment: Actually the producer is a continuous stream but it worked fine as the data was low. but seems like the producer is streaming large amount of data from a few days and consumer always see messages available on the topic.

Comment: In that case, you can use a step-scoped ItemReadListener in which you inject a StepExecution (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710203/5019386) and call `StepExecution#setTerminateOnly`.

Comment: How can i pass time limit to setTerminateOnly() method?

Comment: It's up to you to calculate that and call setTerminateOnly when appropriate.

Comment: If you have something similar already implemented, could you please share that. It would be helpful.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - How setTerminateOnly will exits the job. I am not able to make it work. I created a ReadListener class, in afterRead() method, I am checking if the records date is > yesterday's end date, setting stepExecution.setTerminateOnly() but it is just showing step interrupted and exits

Comment: But that's what you want right? You want to interrupt the job at that point, at least that's what I understood from your question: `How to stop spring batch job [...] after certain time`. If you are talking about the exit status, you can set it as needed on the stepExecution as well, in addition to setting the `terminateOnly` flag.

Comment: Just found this complete example in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511273/5019386. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I didn't want to fail the job instead want to exit it with COMPLETED status only. I am checking the date on the incoming messages and returning NULL if condition doesn't match. Is it going to exit the step for the particular chunk or the entire job? I am not able to test this scenario on lower env due to very less data.